# SQL UNION Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using  SQL Server 2014 and have two table: `ApplicationProjectLO` and `V_SIP_ALLSTAFF`:

Table `ApplicationProjectLO`:

```
|---------------------|---------------------------|
|      StaffEmailId   |             Type          |
|---------------------|---------------------------|
|       chinkim1      |              L            |
|---------------------|---------------------------|
|       kandiah1      |              A            |
|---------------------|---------------------------|
```

Table `V_SIP_ALLSTAFF`

```
|---------------------|----------------|-------------------|---------------|
|      lOGINID        |    displayname |   Email Address   |MainOfficeTelNo|
|---------------------|----------------|----------------   |-------------- |
|      chinkim1       |    james       |        1          |       5       |
|---------------------|----------------|----------------   |---------------|
|      kandiah1       |    hoho        |        2          |       8       |
|---------------------|----------------|----------------   |---------------|
```

I would like to display the information based on 'Type'.

So if the `StaffEmailId` match the `LONGINID` and the type is `A`, the information of type `A` (that is `hoho`, `2`, and `8`) must be displayed, and if type is `L` then it `james`, `1`, and `5` must be displayed.

I tried to use `UNION` and `UNION ALL` to run two select statement in one query but it only return `type=L` result based on this query:

```
SELECT
    vsa.displayname NameofLiaisonOfficer, 
    vsa.EmailAddress LOEmail, 
    '(65)' +' '+ convert(varchar, vsa.MainOfficeTelNo ) as LOContactNo,
    vsa.MainOfficeTelNo GeneralOfficeConatctNo 
FROM ApplicationProjectLo ap
INNER JOIN V_SIP_ALLSTAFF vsa ON ap.StaffEmailId = vsa.LOGINID
WHERE ap.Type = 'L'

UNION ALL

SELECT
    vsa.displayname NameofAlternateLiaisonOfficer, 
    vsa.EmailAddress AlternateLOEmail,
    '(65)' +' '+ convert(varchar, vsa.MainOfficeTelNo ) as AlternateLOContactNo,
    vsa.MainOfficeTelNo GeneralOfficeConatctNo 
FROM ApplicationProjectLo ap
INNER JOIN V_SIP_ALLSTAFF vsa ON ap.StaffEmailId = vsa.LOGINID
WHERE ap.Type = 'A'
```

MVC View:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <strong>Name of Liaison Officer</strong>
        <br />
        <br /> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TPInformationDetails.NameofLiaisonOfficer)
    </td>
    @*
    <td>
        <strong>Room Number</strong>
        <br />
        <br />
    </td>*@
    <td>
        <strong>Contact Number</strong>
        <br />
        <br /> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TPInformationDetails.LOContactNo)
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong>Email Address</strong>
        <br />
        <br /> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TPInformationDetails.LOEmail)
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- Table Row -->
<tr class="even">
    <td colspan="3">
        <strong>Name of Alternate Liaison Officer</strong>
        <br />
        <br /> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TPInformationDetails.NameofAlternateLiaisonOfficer)
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong>Contact Number</strong>
        <br />
        <br /> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TPInformationDetails.AlternateLOContactNo)
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong>Email Address</strong>
        <br />
        <br /> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TPInformationDetails.AlternateLOEmail)
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- Table Row -->
```

Comment: Why are you using union instead of join?

Comment: Can you isolate the problem first. Is MVC related?

Comment: Based on the answer provided, it's not using the model that is bind to the query. For example, NameofLiaisonOfficer, but for Type "A" it's NameofAlternateLiaisonOfficer. If i just use NameofLiaisonOfficer and bind to the view, it will display the same result.

Comment: You can't have a different alias for the subsequent parts of a `UNION (ALL)`. The first alias is used, the rest is ignored. So in your query, only `NameofLiaisonOfficer` is used. If you execute the query you will see that `NameofAlternateLiaisonOfficer` is not an output column.

Comment: Yes, you're right. In that case, how do i join two select statement in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const string _sqlODetails = @"SELECT vsa.displayname NameofLiaisonOfficer, 
                                                 vsa.EmailAddress LOEmail, 
                                                 '(65)' +' '+ convert(varchar, vsa.MainOfficeTelNo ) as LOContactNo, 
                                                 vsa.MainOfficeTelNo GeneralOfficeConatctNo 
                                          FROM ApplicationProjectLo ap 
                                          INNER JOIN V_SIP_ALLSTAFF vsa ON ap.StaffEmailId = vsa.LOGINID 
                                          WHERE ap.Type = 'L'";

            using (var connection = Db.SqlServer())
            {
                tpOdetails = connection
                  .Query<TPInformationDetails>(_sqlODetails)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
            }

            const string _sqlADetails = @"SELECT vsa.displayname NameofAlternateLiaisonOfficer, 
                                                  vsa.EmailAddress AlternateLOEmail,
                                                  '(65)' +' '+ convert(varchar, vsa.MainOfficeTelNo ) as AlternateLOContactNo, 
                                                  vsa.MainOfficeTelNo GeneralOfficeConatctNo 
                                          FROM ApplicationProjectLo ap 
                                          INNER JOIN V_SIP_ALLSTAFF vsa ON ap.StaffEmailId = vsa.LOGINID 
                                          WHERE ap.Type = 'A'";

            using (var connection = Db.SqlServer())

            {
                tpAdetails = connection
                  .Query<TPInformationDetails>(_sqlADetails)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    vsa.displayname NameofLiaisonOfficer, 
    vsa.EmailAddress LOEmail, 
    '(65)' +' '+ convert(varchar, vsa.MainOfficeTelNo ) as LOContactNo, 
    vsa.MainOfficeTelNo GeneralOfficeConatctNo 
FROM ApplicationProjectLo ap 
INNER JOIN V_SIP_ALLSTAFF vsa ON ap.StaffEmailId = vsa.LOGINID 
WHERE ap.Type IN ('A', 'L')
```

Comment: This means i'm only returning values from L, what about A? I returning the values from the same table V_SIP_ALLSTAFF based on type 'A' or 'L' in ApplicationProjectLO.

Comment: @user3807187 oh, it's simpler, than I expected. check updated answer

Comment: Hi, doing that will result same values. Im using MVC, pplease check my updated post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `JOIN`, not an `UNION`. `JOIN` combines columns from two tables based on common `key` `field(s)`.

```
SELECT a.field1, b.field1, b.field2 FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.keyfield=b.keyfield;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just dispense wth the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT vsa.displayname as NameofLiaisonOfficer, 
       vsa.EmailAddress LOEmail, 
      '(65)' +' '+ convert(varchar, vsa.MainOfficeTelNo ) as LOContactNo,
       vsa.MainOfficeTelNo GeneralOfficeConatctNo 
FROM ApplicationProjectLo ap INNER JOIN
      V_SIP_ALLSTAFF vsa
      ON ap.StaffEmailId = vsa.LOGINID;
```

Or use a `WHERE` that includes both types:

```
SELECT vsa.displayname as NameofLiaisonOfficer, 
       vsa.EmailAddress LOEmail, 
      '(65)' +' '+ convert(varchar, vsa.MainOfficeTelNo ) as LOContactNo,
       vsa.MainOfficeTelNo GeneralOfficeConatctNo 
FROM ApplicationProjectLo ap INNER JOIN
      V_SIP_ALLSTAFF vsa
      ON ap.StaffEmailId = vsa.LOGINID;
WHERE ap.Type IN ('A', 'L');
```

That said, it is unclear why your query -- although over-complicated -- is not returning both types.  One possibility is that you are using a national character set and the "A" is not really an "A".

Comment: Hi, doing that will result same values. Im using MVC, pplease check my updated post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query to display the result with type 'L' and 'A'.

```
SELECT
    vsa.displayname NameofLiaisonOfficer, 
    vsa.EmailAddress LOEmail, 
    '(65)' +' '+ convert(varchar, vsa.MainOfficeTelNo ) as LOContactNo, 
    vsa.MainOfficeTelNo GeneralOfficeConatctNo 
FROM ApplicationProjectLo ap 
INNER JOIN V_SIP_ALLSTAFF vsa ON ap.StaffEmailId = vsa.LOGINID 
WHERE ap.Type IN ('L','A')
ORDER BY ap.Type desc
```

Comment: Hi, doing that will result same values. Im using MVC, pplease check my updated post. Thanks.